# How to override onBackPressed in Custom Chrome Tabs

Tags: java, android

I need this :

1. Open CCT
2. Close Main Activity
3. If it's first page, onBackPressed do nothing (don't close app too)
4. If it isn't first page, onBackPressed do what it gotta do

Code :

```
    private void OpenCCT(String url) {
        String CUSTOM_TAB_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.android.chrome";
        CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();

        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = intentBuilder.build();
        customTabsIntent.intent.setPackage(CUSTOM_TAB_PACKAGE_NAME);

        customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));

        finish();
    }
```